# Change Sound Profile in Android

Tags: android

I want to change **Sound Profile** of the phone when i click the button does anybody has idea how can i do it? I have searched but unable to find the solution to the problems.

Comment: You need to specify exactly what you mean by "sound profiles".

Comment: General, Silent, Vibrate Sound profiles which changes from setting i want to change it by coding.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can accomplish this with the `AudioManager` [setRingerMode](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/media/AudioManager.html#setRingerMode%28int%29) method. For example:

```
AudioManager audioManager = getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);
audioManager.setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);
```

This might require the `MODIFY_AUDIO_SETTINGS` permission. Note also that other apps can override your setting.

Comment: shortest version is getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE).setRingerMode(AudioManager.RINGER_MODE_VIBRATE);